Cartesian cross joins in Doctrine
Using Doctrine, is it possible to do Cartesian cross joins?
Example:
SELECT * FROM t1, t2 WHERE ...

Where t1 and t2 represent entities, and is it possible to attach the retrieved entities to the unit of work?
Thank you
EDIT: Yes, I am aware that a similar question exists, but the accepted answer was chosen 10 years ago. Perhaps things changed then.

This question is similar to: Cross Join to DQL. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
